# Are there any taxes due when exercising ISOs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options

I had some ISOs from a US-based startup. I held these for a few years already if that matters. I wanted to exercise 900 shares at $3.3, for some reason the total I need to pay is $16.5K. Main reason mentioned is tax liability, however, afaik, there is no tax liability when exercising ISOs. Any idea what is going on? Were the rules changed recently?

[image]

Comment: ISOs are subject to AMT, but generally, that's not done through withholding.

Comment: Re: the possibility these are NSOs - in Shareworks go to "Portfolio", "Stock Options and Awards", "Account Summary", and look if there's a column in between "Expire / Cancel Date" and "Post-Termination Exercise Period" called "ISO Disqualification Date".

Comment: Oh, yes, all of them list a date, even those that weren’t supposed to. I’m wondering what made them disqualified?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exercising 900 ISOs at $3.33/sh = $2,997 exercise cost. That means the tax liability associated is $13,444.60 - that's only really feasible if the spread is at least $48,000 (the tax liability/0.28, which is the top AMT bracket). The current FMV would have to be $56.66, but likely much higher, in order to be incurring this much AMT.

Big question - are YOU in the U.S.? If you're not, then these have almost certainly converted into NSOs, which do have tax withholding on the spread (FMV - exercise price).

I also know that Roblox (not sure if you meant to leave the name in there) gave employees the option to convert ISOs to NSOs a few years back - did you participate in that?

Continuing my stream of consciousness - NSOs make sense here. RBLX is trading at $40.05, which gives you a spread of $36.92/sh, or $33,048 for 900 shares. Tax liability of $13,444.60 / spread of $33,048 gives an effective tax rate of 40.78%. 22% federal + 10.23% CA (big assumption here) + 7.65% FICA + 0.9% additional Medicare tax = 40.78%, although having full FICA + additional Medicare tax is very uncommon.

Comment: Yes, I did participate once, one grant is converted to NSOs, but when I try to exercise all of them have the same issue

Comment: I see a random date set as disqualification date. Any idea what could it be related to?

Comment: I’m not in the US now. Can these be converted back to ISOs if I come back to the US?

Comment: Is the disqualifying date around the time you left the US/told the company you were leaving the US? Another possibility, if you're no longer at the company and it's been >90 days since you left, your ISOs automatically converted to NSOs.

Comment: Yes, the date is the 90 days since I left. I'm screwed big time cause I didn't know about it

Comment: Do you happen to know any tax adviser who is proficient with ISO/NSOs + non-US person (half vested while being resident alien, half vested while remote)? All of tax advisers I tried to talk to in the bay area seem to have absolutely no clue when I checked with them.

Comment: Checking. This may be tax attorney territory rather than CPA/EA. It's a little tough since we're in the middle of filing season. How much longer do you have on those NSOs - are we talking weeks/months or years?

Comment: A couple of years, should be ok.

Comment: @PavelP I have a potential referral for you. Don't want to drop their info here - let me know the best way to get it to you.

Comment: Can you please dm it on twitter:pps831?

Answer (score 2):

You specified Incentive Stock Options (ISOs) in your question.  **Non-Qualified Stock Options** (NSO or NQSO) are different, in a bad way.  I'll cover those at the bottom. Avoid these if you can.

### Normally, you are not taxed for buying a stock

"To exercise" a stock option generally means "to buy the stock" at the option price (generally below market).

You're not taxed for *buying* a stock... **Unless it's the ugly NSO/NQSO**.  Your advantageous strike price simply becomes your cost basis.

### You pay tax on sale, at varying rates. Or not.

You are taxed when you sell. The rate varies wildly, from $0 to normal income tax rates.

If you sell within 12 months, then you are taxed at the normal income-tax rates, so it's essentially the same bad scenario as an NQSO.   **If you wait 12 months or longer, you are taxed at the *much lower* long-term capital gains rates**.   Either way, your advantageous buy price is your *cost basis*.

But my father and I prefer paying $0 tax.

My father held those stocks for a lifetime (they pay good dividends). Dad's estate would pay the capital gains tax, except it won't, because the estate isn't large enough to be taxed. So 50 years of capital gains tax *just disappears*.  The person who inherit them will have their *cost basis* reset to market price on date of death.

Most of my bought stock options, I held for over a year and gave to "my" Donor Advised Fund, which is a charity. They sold the stock, and they paid tax at their charity capital gains rate of 0%.  I then re-donate to my charities out of that fund.  This allows me to get a tax benefit from the charitable giving I'm going to do *anyway*, without having to itemize deductions on IRS schedule A.

### Non-qualified stock options are hot mess

These follow a special and not-particularly-nice rule.  When you exercise (buy) a NQSO, your "cost basis" is actually market price for the day.  You pay less due to your option, **and the difference is treated as regular income, on the day you buy**.

Suppose you exercise 900 shares worth $50,000 market price today, and pay $3000 due to your option. With NQSOs aka NSOs, $47,000 is considered income that year, subject to regular income tax (i.e. the worst way to pay tax on a capital gain). They will withhold accordingly, typically at an arbitrary and fixed 22% Federal rate (37% if your income is above $1,000,000).

The cost basis is then the normal market price for the day, i.e. the $50,000.  If you sell it in 2026 for $70,000, then in 2026 you pay the favorable long-term capital gains tax on the $20,000.

As you can see, there is no tax advantage for holding these stocks any length of time - you might as well immediately sell and buy another more rounded investment like an index fund.

So I would do everything possible to avoid treatment of your options as NSO/NQSO.  I would haggle with your employer and see if you can get them treated as regular stock options.